# confusion Memory of Quran or Translate

Tags: quran, tafseer, sunnah, shirk, islamic-basis

I tried to memorize the Holy Qur'an in my childhood, but it didn't work. I used to forget the lesson after 2 days, but I completed the memorization and counted myself among the Quran memorizers, but now I want to start again. What should I do to memorize the Qur'an or translate and interpret the Qur'an?

Comment: Translating and interpreting require different skills than memorizing. If you mean studying a translation or interpretation then yes it might help in memorizing but generally you memorize by repetition of learning and recall.